# How to keep dividing a number by its lowest factor till the number becomes 1 in Java

Tags: java

I want a program in which if the user enters a number, for example 20, then it should divide the number by 2(the first non-one factor) and get 10. Then it should check if this number if one or not. If it is then divide by 2 and get 5, and finally divide 5 and get 1. Then the program should stop. But I am unable to understand what step to do after dividing the first number. Then in the end the output should be 20+10+5+1 which is 36. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        //Write code here

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String val = s.nextLine();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(val);
        int total = 0;

        String num = s.nextLine();
        String[] strings = num.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
            int current = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
            if(current == 1){
                total ++;
            } else if(current > 1){
                total += current + 1;
                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int j = 2; j<=current; j++){
                    if(current % j == 0){
                        numbers.add(j);
                    }
                }
                total += current / numbers.get(0);
            } else if (current < 0){
                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = current; j <= current * -1; j++){
                    numbers.add(j);
                }
                total += current / numbers.get(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}   

 import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class PrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        //Write code here

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String val = s.nextLine();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(val);
        int total = 0;

        String num = s.nextLine();
        String[] strings = num.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
            int current = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
            if(current == 1){
                total ++;
            } else if(current > 1){
                total += current + 1;
                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int j = 2; j<=current; j++){
                    if(current % j == 0){
                        numbers.add(j);
                    }
                }
                total += current / numbers.get(0);
            } else if (current < 0){
                ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = current; j <= current * -1; j++){
                    numbers.add(j);
                }
                total += current / numbers.get(0);
            }
        }
    System.out.println(total);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger in an IDE?  Have you tried doing a walkthrough making a table of values on paper step by step?

Comment: Your program demands input from the user but does not `System.out.println` instructions to the user.  Please edit the code to help members help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not need to be that complicated. There are couple of things that were missing in the code that is provided in the question.
First, `total` is not being set to 0 for every number. Second, you are only dividing only once for one factor.

Below is an example for calculating output for one number. You can use this as a function in your code.

```java
import java.util.*;
class PrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = s.nextInt();
        int total = num;
        int factor = 2;
        while (factor <= num) {
            if (num % factor == 0) {
                total += num/factor;
                num = num / factor;
            } else {
                factor++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code fails because it always uses factor == 2.  It does not receive or calculate the primes.  It does demand input from the user with no instructions.

Comment: Thanks @Alan for pointing out the glaring mistake.

Comment: (thanks)  Your edited code fails because it does not use prime factors.

Comment: It would always use prime factors only. Any composite number would not come to picture since that numbers' factor would have already divided the original number.

Consider the example for number 200. It is divisible by 10. But we already divide it with 2 and 5 separately, before the factor becomes 10.

Comment: Can you provide an example where it fails?

Comment: Okay "fail" was too strong.  However,  it could be better. 1) It will try many numbers without success, essentially finding primes as well as doing the task. 2) I think l_b enters a list of factors manually, 3) It does three divisions instead of two. 4) If number is prime it loops all the way up to number instead of half way.

Comment: Jalaj, I'm sorry if I've been too harsh.  Your code seems correct by inspection by eye and is simple which is often good for teaching.  I often see certain optimizations or efficiencies by habit.